# Slideshow with many image boxs sliding

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

making slideshow section, which contain images positioned side by side with different sizes like previewed below, each color box is sliding images (whatever the effect is),

bootstrap's slider doesn't give the power to make something like this

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

any ideas

[image: Slider sample]

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what you want because it's quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstraps carousel works fine if you use the correct markup and classes. It will work with images of different sizes and the slider will change each slide.

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: will have to make it separated slide shows, wont be very clean

Comment: If you set up each of the sections as sliders with the correct markup you shouldn't have an issue? But yes they will have to be separate sliders otherwise how will they know the context in which to slide. Same JS for all of them though. See: http://jsfiddle.net/aaAeg/